# Which of multiple checkboxes is singly checked? I need it's cell reference

Tags: google-sheets

I am seeking a worksheet formula to ideally return the **cell column letter** (or at least the cell reference) of the checkbox that is *checked from a range of checkboxes*.

Given this range of checkboxes(F1:J1)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ss4Q7.jpg

[image]

I'd like to give the user the option to choose a **single** one of these AND then know which one was picked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)?

Comment: Hi... go and study a good example of radio buttons at https://kierandixon.com/radio-buttons-google-sheets/

Answer (score 1):

Use `arrayformula(if())`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  if(F1:J1 = TRUE, COLUMN(F1:J1),"") 
)
```

The formula will give you the number of the column.

Consider to edit your question and leave only the necessary information. Also if there is additional criteria how the formula should work to describe it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `regexextract(address())`, like this:

`=arrayformula( iferror( regexextract( join( "", if( F1:J1, address(1, column(F1:J1)), "" ) ), "[A-Z]" ) ) )`